# Python: Conditional Substraction

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

My goal is to calculate the thickness [m] of each layer for each id, based on the depth [m] of each layer. The following is a dataframe similar to mine.

```
eID = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3]
depth = [0.35,1.5,3.0,0.75,2.0,0.2,0.8,1.7,3.5]
dictex ={"id":eID,"depth [m]":depth}
dfe = pd.DataFrame(dictex)
print(dfe)

   id  depth [m]
0   1       0.35
1   1       1.50
2   1       3.00
3   2       0.75
4   2       2.00
5   3       0.20
6   3       0.80
7   3       1.70
8   3       3.50
```

There are two conditions to be considered:

1. If there is no layer with a smaller depth for an id, then this depth is equal to the thickness.
2. If there is a layer with a smaller depth, the previous depth has to be substracted from the current depth to calculate the thickness.

The result should look like this:

```
   id  depth [m]  thickness [m]
0   1       0.35           0.35
1   1       1.50           1.15
2   1       3.00           1.50
3   2       0.75           0.75
4   2       2.00           1.25
5   3       0.20           0.20
6   3       0.80           0.60
7   3       1.70           0.90
8   3       3.50           1.80
```

I've tried working with "groupby", "np.where" and a for-loop with if-conditions, but unfortunately i haven't been able to get it to work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please share the code you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If values are sorted per groups use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with replace first values per groups by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by original values:

```
dfe['thickness [m]s'] = dfe.groupby('id')['depth [m]'].diff().fillna(dfe['depth [m]'])
print (dfe)
   id  depth [m]  thickness [m]s
0   1       0.35            0.35
1   1       1.50            1.15
2   1       3.00            1.50
3   2       0.75            0.75
4   2       2.00            1.25
5   3       0.20            0.20
6   3       0.80            0.60
7   3       1.70            0.90
8   3       3.50            1.80
```